# How to set Firefox profile using RemoteWebDriver(.Net)

Tags: .net, webdriver

Has the ability to set Firefox profile with RemoteWebDriver (.Net) been deprecated?  Perhaps it was never implemented for .Net.  I've found samples for Java, but I'm not sure how current they are, and there doesn't appear to be method to apply a profile to a remote FirefoxDriver.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this in the latest code in the trunk. Your code would look something like this (*warning:* untested code):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
// customize your profile here...

DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
caps.SetCapability("firefox_profile", profile.ToBase64String());

IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(caps);
```

Please note that the code that allows this hasn't been released in an official release yet, but is available in the trunk. It will be available in the next release of the project.

Comment: Two follow on questions:  When might the next release be coming out?  and  How would one accomplish something similar with IE?  I'm particularly interested in picking up a string value in the User Agent.  I've already added the string to the registry on my remote server machine, and the string is picked up if I or another user logs in and starts IE, but for some reason, the RemoteWebDriver instances of IE are not picking up this string from the registry.  Thanks.

Comment: The "next release" is coming out soon. I can't be more specific. Of course, the project is an open source project, so you can always obtain the source and [build the very latest bits yourself](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/BuildingWebDriver). IE doesn't have the concept of a "profile". Its settings are global to the system for the currently logged-in user. I'm not sure why IE wouldn't pick up the change. It would be interesting to take the remote server out of the equation, simply instantiating the InternetExplorerDriver class directly, and seeing if it contains the user-agent string.

Comment: Yes, instantiating InternetExplorerDriver locally DOES pick up the User Agent string added to the registry. Incidently, for IE 8, on Win7 64-bit, the location to add the string value is: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\User Agent\Post Platform

Comment: After trying a number of different ways to include the profile in the capabilities object, it doesn't appear to be working.  I'd be interested in hearing whether anyone has actually been able to use a custom profile for Firefox with RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: The problem is due to [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1579) in the Java FirefoxProfile class which is used by the remote server. There is a patch attached to the bug which will fix the issue as soon as it's applied.